# How do I make new Google Search look like old Google Search using CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I am trying to make the new Google Search results look like the old Google Search results.

The new design has the domain link above the page title which is really confusing.  The domain link also used to be colored green which made the search results page much easier to read but now it isn't.

This is how I want the Google Search results page to look like:

[image]

So, as you can see, the weblink is green and positioned under the title for each result.  This is what I want.

So I have created an extension and so far I have changed the color of the domain link to green (as it used to be) using just CSS:

```
.iUh30{
    color:green !important;
}
```

However, I want this domain link to be below the search title (as it used to be).

Is it possible to do this using CSS or JavaScript in my extension?

There is an existing extension here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bring-classic-back/klnhfpnhipgjannlklfcnhonncppnoae

But it doesn't work properly with the latest update from Google.

Thank you for reading.

Update:
I can achieve most of what I want by using this for my CSS file:

```
.iUh30{
    color:green !important;
}

.NJjxre {
    position: relative !important;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

That displays the weblink perfectly.  The only problem is the dropdown menu (used for selecting cached pages).  How can I move this dropdown menu to the right of the green weblink (or remove it completely without leaving any vacant space where it would normally be?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: My original answer is below.  However, since I made this answer, I have started using a Chrome extension called [Make Google search great again](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/make-google-search-great/meigofcidjeckljcajpedlihfenjldbi) which has been working great.  So I suggest you install that.

So I solved this (for the moment) with the extension code I will post below.  The code is based on a [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) script which you can see [here](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/395257-better-google/code).  So if you use TamperMonkey, there is no need to create an extension at all as the script works at this moment in time.

But if you prefer to create an extension for this, here is the code that I am using.

Note that the below works with Google.co.uk only.  If you use another Google country domain, change the matches and exclude_matches sections in manifest.json accordindly.

**styles.css**

```
.NJjxre {position: relative !important;}
.btrG {word-break: break-all; line-height: 18px;}
.btrG .btrAdd { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;}
.btrG .btrLink {display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; line-height: 18px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: none !important;}
.btrG .btrLink cite.iUh30 {color: #006621; font-size: 16px;}
.B6fmyf {display:none;}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{

    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Google Search Classic",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Classic Google Search.",

    "icons": { 
           "48": "icon1.png",
          "128": "icon2.png"
    },
          
    "content_scripts": [{
        "css": ["styles.css"],
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "matches": ["https://www.google.co.uk/*"],
        "exclude_matches": ["https://www.google.co.uk/*tbm=vid*"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }]

}
```

**content.js**

```
var el = document.querySelector('#rcnt');
if (el != null){document.querySelectorAll('.g .rc').forEach(function(el){

    var tbwUpd = el.querySelectorAll('.TbwUpd');
    if (tbwUpd.length > 0){

        var linkEl = el.querySelector('.r > a');
        var addEl = linkEl.nextSibling;
        var betterAddEl = document.createElement('div');
        betterAddEl.className = 'btrAdd';

        if (addEl){
            for (var i = 0; i < addEl.children.length; i++) {
                var _el = addEl.children[i];
                if (_el.className.indexOf('TbwUpd') == -1) {
                    betterAddEl.appendChild(_el);
                }
            }
        }

        var betterEl = document.createElement('div');
        betterEl.className = 'btrG';
        betterEl.appendChild(betterAddEl);

        el.querySelector('.r').appendChild(betterEl);

        var urlEl = document.createElement('a');
        urlEl.href = linkEl.href;
        urlEl.target = '_blank';
        urlEl.className = 'btrLink';

        var urlCiteEl = document.createElement('cite');
        urlCiteEl.innerText = linkEl.href;
        urlCiteEl.className = 'iUh30 bc';
        urlEl.appendChild(urlCiteEl);

        var maxWidth = el.clientWidth - betterAddEl.offsetWidth - 10;

        betterEl.insertBefore(urlEl, betterAddEl);
        if (urlEl.offsetWidth > maxWidth){
            urlEl.style.width = maxWidth.toString() + 'px';
        }

        tbwUpd.forEach(function(el){el.remove()});
        linkEl.querySelector('br:first-child').remove();

    }

});}
```

Just put the above into a new folder, add icon1.png and icon2.png and use Chrome to pack it into an extension.  To avoid the Chrome developer warning, use the packed extension (not the unpacked one) and whitelist the extension ID in the registry.

The only downside to this is a small delay while the search results are reformatted.  Also the Ad results are not formatted but I don't think that matters since they are only ads.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like this should work:

```
.NJjxre {
    position: relative !important;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.  That is almost perfect but some results show the weblink to the right of the title and not underneath it.  Is there any way to fix that?  Also the 'Translate this page' link that appears sometimes is shown above the weblink.  Could this be shown to the right of the weblink instead?

Comment: Also the dropdown menu with 'Cached' item also appears in the wrong place.

Comment: I got it to always show the weblink under the title by adding width: 1000px; inside your CSS code.  So that only leaves the dropdown button (for showing cached pages).  I can hide the dropdown menu button by setting visibility:hidden; for .GHDvEf but that still leaves a blank line for where the dropdown button would normally be.  How can I remove this blank line so the search results aren't spaced out so much?  I have tried display: none on the dropdown button (.GHDvEf) but that didn't work.

Comment: Edit to the above comment: Moving the dropdown button to the right of the weblink would be great but if not then hiding it would suffice.  But I'd prefer it if it didn't leave a space where the button would normally be and I don't know how to do this (display: none doesn't work).

Comment: Setting display: none; to .B6fmyf hides the dropdown menu but again, there is stilll a blank line space where the dropdown menu would normally be.  I need to find a way of removing this blank line space.